# How to dynamically add button/fragment based on user requirements

Tags: java, android

I'm a newbie in android. I have an electrical device that is controlled by mobile app through Wifi. The mobile app turns the electrical device ON/OFF, and also sets the operation time of the electrical device. I can write an android app to control the operation of one or a specific number of electrical devices. That's, the number of electrical devices is static. But, the question is how to write an android app to control unknown number of devices. That's, I want to develop an android app that gives the user the ability to dynamically add and control new devices. As I early mentioned, I'm a newbie in android and I don't know how to do this. Should the android app dynamically add a new button or fragment? Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Edit:
Here is what I tried to do. In the app's menu, I have "Add New Device" tap. When I click it, the app navigates into two or three fragments until it reaches the final fragment that stores the electrical device information (IP address, port number, etc.). Up to this point, I'm OK. What I'm trying to do now is to save/store this final fragment as a button to be shown on the main page of the app. That is, whenever I add a new device, I will end up having a new button shown on the main page of the app

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this problem would be to work out how many buttons you need during your `onCreate` method. You can then create this many buttons, maybe as an array. A quick example could be

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  int numButtons;
  //calculate the number of buttons you will need

  Button buttons[numButtons];

  for (int i = 0;i < numButtons;i++) {
    buttons[i] = new Button("Button " + String.valueOf(i+1));
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //code for when button 'i' is pressed.
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. In fact, a button by itself cannot do the required job as I mentioned in my question that adding a new electrical device will require more than a button to turn the device on/off and to adjust its operation time.

Comment: @Mike you're already on the right track then if you know that you are able to use fragments to solve your problem. You could create a custom fragment and do something similar to what I did with the buttons. You might consider just using a Spinner instead, and a single button. That way you could choose the button you want from the drop down menu and have one big button that will act according to what is selected in the spinner. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: Thanks again toastedDeli for your help. Spinner will require that the number of devices is known a head of time. Here is what I tried to do. In my menu, I have "Add New Device" tap. When I click it, the app navigates into two or three fragments until it reaches the final fragment that stores the electrical device information (Ip address, port number, etc.). Up to this point, I'm OK. What I'm trying to do now is to save/store this final fragment as a button to be shown on main page of app. That is, whenever I add a new device, I will end up having a new button shown on the main page of the app.

Comment: @Mike you need to access the local storage on the phone and save information that will allow you to re build this in the app on startup. Depending on how important security is, this might not be the best solution. Either way, you need to "save" something that will allow you to re create your app. You don't need to save the fragments, you just need to save whatever information it is that makes that fragment unique. For your application, this might be ip or MAC addresses of devices you want to control

Comment: @Mike the most basic way I can imagine of implementing this would be to save ip address/port number pairs line by line to a plain text file on the device. Your app can then read this on startup and for every line, it can create a new button that opens the appropriate connection etc.

Comment: @Mike also, you don't need to know how many buttons youll need to make a spinner. you can use an ArrayAdapter (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) to dynamically funnel things into a spinner (among other things)

Comment: Thank you toastedDeli so much for your invaluable suggestions. Yes, you're right that I only need to save the information I got in the final fragment (ip address and port number) into a plain text file.So, based on what I understood from your suggestion,  I should use the saved information to create/add dynamic buttons to the main page of the app. The number of buttons will be defined based on the number of lines saved in the text file.